# CSS or C++ for GUI

Tags: c++, qt, interface

I am just wondering which of those two is the more convenient for designing a GUI.
Should I use CSS for styling my application or do it by hand using Qt functions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS has been proven simpler and cheaper to maintain and modify than requiring messing with the source code and recompiling it. It also provides a better separation between application logic and presentation.

Comment: And should i use an external style sheet ? Or style one by one ? :)

Comment: Keeping with the `separation` argument, it'd be better to use external files. Theme'ing is easier this way.

Answer (score 2):

If I ware you. I will select CSS as much as possible.